# Symfony Twig customize an Individual field for a collection

Tags: symfony, twig

In the documentation there is a way in Symfony to [customize a Individual field](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#how-to-customize-an-individual-field), based on the name/id of the widget.

```
{% form_theme form _self %}

{% block _product_name_widget %}
    <div class="text_widget">
        {{ block('field_widget') }}
    </div>
{% endblock %}

{{ form_widget(form.name) }}
```

Here, the _product_name_widget fragment defines the template to use for the field whose id is product_name (and name is product[name]).

This works for a normal widget, but not if a widget is inside a collection. Because of the extra columns. Like this:

```
name="productbundle_product_type[foobar][1][value]" id="productbundle_product_type_foobar_1_value"
```

What is the way to make the Twig customization work inside the collection?

I thought something like this, but that doesn't work:

```
{% for db in edit_form.list %}
    {% block _productbundle_product_type_foobar_{{ db.name }}_widget %}
        <div class="text_widget">
            {{ block('field_widget') }}
        </div>
    {% endblock %}
{% endfor %}
```

Even the following doesn't work:

```
{% _productbundle_product_type_foobar_1_value_widget %}
```

What is the way to make it work?

Comment: And if you use `{% block _productbundle_product_type_foobar_1_{{ db.name }}_widget %}` (with the `_1_`)

Comment: no, the following also does not work: `{% _productbundle_product_type_foobar_1_value_widget %}`

Comment: I am surprised because the doc states: `Here, the _product_name_widget fragment defines the template to use for the field whose id is product_name (and name is product[name]).` So if the name of your widget is `productbundle_product_type[foobar][1][value]` you should be able to use `{% block _productbundle_product_type_foobar_1_value_widget %}`

Comment: The docs are refering to 'normal' form_widgets I guess, not form_widgets in a Collection. But indeed, it's strange. Thats why I'm asking the question. :-)

Answer (score 3):

I was working on a project a couple of evenings ago and encountered precisely this problem - the solution I found is a pair of blocks that look like this (stripped of project-specific code):

```
{# Collection markup #}
{% block my_collection_widget %}
    {# Customise collection row prototype for allow_add #}
    {% if prototype is defined %}
        {% set data_prototype = block('my_collection_item_widget')  %}
        <div id="my_prototype" data-prototype="{{ data_prototype }}" style="display: none"></div>
    {% endif %}

    {% for prototype in form %}
        {{ block('my_collection_item_widget') }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock my_collection_widget %}

{# Collection row markup #}
{% block my_collection_item_widget %}
    {# Collection contains simple, single type #}
    {{ form_errors(prototype) }}
    {{ form_label(prototype) }}
    {{ form_widget(prototype) }}

    {# OR #}

    {# Collection contains a compound type, render child types independantly #}
    {{ form_errors(prototype.inner_widget) }}
    {{ form_label(prototype.inner_widget) }}
    {{ form_widget(prototype.inner_widget) }}
{% endblock my_collection_item_widget %}
```

Comment: 'Method "inner_widget" doesn't exist'. Method "inner_widget". What has to be the name of My_collection_widget? _productbundle_product_type_foobar_widget does not work.I guess it does not meet the requirements i need.

Comment: Replace 'my_collection' in both blocks with the name of the collection in the form you're rendering.

Inside the *_item_widget block you provide the custom markup for a single item in the collection; if your collection is simple (a single type) then simply call {{ form_*(prototype) }} with whatever custom markup you want. If the collection is more complex (each collection item contains several types) then the above example shows you how to customise each embedded type.

Comment: Where not on the same page I guess :-) I'm just showing a collection, without the possibility to add more. `$builder ->add('foobar', 'collection', array( 'type' => new ProductbundleProductType(), ));`

Comment: The principle should be the same; if ProductbundleProductType is a simple (eg a type extension) then the code at the top of "my_collection_item_widget" should work, if it is more complex then a repetition of the code at the bottom of the block should work (replacing "inner_widget" with the name of each type inside ProductbundleProductType).

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old question, but maybe people still happening upon this. This is explained [fragment naming for collections](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_themes.html#fragment-naming-for-collections).

You use `_entry_` in these cases in place of the collection element number. Use the instructions in the link for fragment naming, but this might vary. Sometimes 'type' is part of the fragment's name, sometimes first letter is upper case, sometimes lower case, etc. I would use a browser developer tool to find the actual name to make sure. You might also be able to customize the names used by adding the getBlockPrefix function to the form class.

Therefore, in your case above, the customized block might look something like:

```
{% block _ProductBundle_product_entry_widget %}
   <div> {{ form_row(form.field)}} </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Where 'field' would be the name of a field in the element of your collection.

Answer (score 1):

A few things here:

**1. Documentation Error**

The [docs seem to be a bit off](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_themes.html#form-custom-prototype) with CamelCase entities. As for 5.3 it should be: `_taskManager_taskLists_entry_widget` (instead of `_task_manager_task_lists_entry_widget`)

You can confirm the naming by dumping the form or form field: `{{ dump(form) }}` or `{{ dump(form.yourField) }}` in your template and then look for `unique_block_prefix` within the `vars` section.

**2. Do NOT use the block overrides, macros are much more easy**

It makes things absolutely more complicated than necessary. Simply define a macro:

```
{% import _self as formMacros %}
{% macro formatCollection(form) %}
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div>
            {{ form_widget(form.field1) }}
            {{ form_widget(form.field2) }}
            {{ form_widget(form.field3) }}
        </div>
    </div>
{% endmacro %}
```

then simply run it on each collection:

```
{% for item in form.collectionItems %}
    {{ formMacros.formatCollection(item) }}
{% endfor %}
```

**3. Prototype**

Get the prototype *before* rendering the collection field. You can store it in a variable.

```
{% set prototype = form.collection.vars.prototype %}
```

Then simply render it whenever you like using our macro:

```
<div data-js="collection" data-prototype="{{ formMacros.formatCollection(prototype)|e('html_attr') }}">
```

Comment: This makes it all so much clearer! Thanks a lot